# Tesseract Node.js - using "lang" option leads to crash

Tags: javascript, node.js, ocr, tesseract

A basic usage of Tesseract.js with a different language than english makes the whole system crash:

```
var options = {
    lang: 'deu',
};

var image = require("path").join(__dirname, 'lib/images/ocr-test-text.png');

var Tesseract = require('tesseract.js')

Tesseract.recognize(image, options)
.progress(function (info) {
    console.log(info);
})
.then(function (data) {
    console.log('done', data);
    process.exit();
})
```

triggers the following error:

```
> node index.js
{ status: 'loading tesseract core' }
{ status: 'loaded tesseract core' }
{ status: 'initializing tesseract', progress: 0 }
pre-main prep time: 68 ms
{ status: 'initializing tesseract', progress: 1 }
{ status: 'downloading deu.traineddata.gz',
  loaded: 116,
  progress: 0.00011697604814572795 }
events.js:182
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: incorrect header check
    at Gunzip.zlibOnError (zlib.js:146:15)
```

Github issue: https://github.com/naptha/tesseract.js/issues/129

Any idea what's happening?

Update:
After following the instruction from the first answer, and download the "deu" traineddata, following error comes up:

```
export TESSDATA_PREFIX=/opt/TESSDATA && node get-text-from-image.js /opt/app/out/image.png
params [ '/opt/app/out/image.png' ]
progress { status: 'loading tesseract core' }
progress { status: 'loaded tesseract core' }
progress { status: 'initializing tesseract', progress: 0 }
pre-main prep time: 62 ms
progress { status: 'initializing tesseract', progress: 1 }
progress { status: 'loading deu.traineddata', progress: 0 }
progress { status: 'loading deu.traineddata', progress: 1 }
progress { status: 'initializing api', progress: 0 }
Failed loading language 'deu'
Tesseract couldn't load any languages!
progress { status: 'initializing api', progress: 0.3 }
progress { status: 'initializing api', progress: 0.6 }
progress { status: 'initializing api', progress: 1 }
progress { status: 'recognizing text', progress: 0 }
AdaptedTemplates != NULL:Error:Assert failed:in file ../classify/adaptmatch.cpp, line 190

/opt/app/node_modules/tesseract.js-core/index.js:4
function f(a){throw a;}var h=void 0,i=!0,j=null,k=!1;function aa(){return function(){}}function ba(a){return function(){return a}}var n,Module;Module||(Module=eval("(function() { try { return TesseractCore || {} } catch(e) { return {} } })()"));var ca={},da;for(da in Module)Module.hasOwnProperty(da)&&(ca[da]=Module[da]);var ea=i,fa=!ea&&i;
              ^
abort() at Error
    at Na (/opt/app/node_modules/tesseract.js-core/index.js:32:26)
    at Object.ka [as abort] (/opt/app/node_modules/tesseract.js-core/index.js:507:108)
    at _abort (/opt/app/node_modules/tesseract.js-core/index.js:373:173)
    at $L (/opt/app/node_modules/tesseract.js-core/index.js:383:55709)
    at jpa (/opt/app/node_modules/tesseract.js-core/index.js:388:22274)
    at lT (/opt/app/node_modules/tesseract.js-core/index.js:387:80568)
    at mT (/opt/app/node_modules/tesseract.js-core/index.js:387:80700)
    at Array.BS (/opt/app/node_modules/tesseract.js-core/index.js:387:69011)
    at bP (/opt/app/node_modules/tesseract.js-core/index.js:383:110121)
    at jT (/opt/app/node_modules/tesseract.js-core/index.js:387:80280)
If this abort() is unexpected, build with -s ASSERTIONS=1 which can give more information.
```

Answer (score 1):

It's failing to unpack deu.traineddata.gz - no idea why. You might want to download the file yourself and try to gunzip it by hand. This isn't the way suggested by the [module creator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-tesseract) though; here's something else you can try.

Download the language files on the machine running node.js and place them somewhere.

https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata

In the environment, make sure the variable `TESSDATA_PREFIX` points to that location. For example, you may put them in `/opt/tessdata`. If you do so, you can set `TESSDATA_PREFIX` like this:

```
export TESSDATA_PREFIX=/opt/tessdata
```

Try again; this time it shouldn't try to download and unpack them itself.

Comment: thank you! I've tried your second suggestion - download and set the env var, but that outputs a different error.

Comment: Did you actually put the files in `/opt/tessdata`? I meant it as an example, you're supposed to substitute `/opt/tessdata` for the directory where you actually put them. Sorry for the confusion, I edited my answer.